# What am I doing wrong in checking if the mail already exist in MySQLI?

Tags: php

So, I got a code to check if the mail is already registrated in the users database.. But when I try to register using the same mail as registrated, it don't trigger the code.
I tried to print the result and I used the code as IsValidUser("themail"); and it returned 1. But still it wont trigger the registration code..
Here's how I check it;

```
if(IsValidUser($reg_email) == 1) {
            $result = '<script>var iframe = document.createElement("IFRAME");iframe.setAttribute("src", "data:text/plain,");document.documentElement.appendChild(iframe);window.frames[0].window.alert("Error\nThis mail adress are already registrated.");iframe.parentNode.removeChild(iframe);</script>';
        }
```

and here's the function;

```
function IsValidUser($mail) {
global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE mail = '$mail'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if(!$result)
    die("Error description: " . mysqli_error($conn));
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Quentin Don't listen, his comment make 0 sense. Or at least i don't understand what he is trying to say...

Comment: What do you mean? I insert the $reg_mail as $mail in the function then check if there's more than 0 rows(over 1) but the $result is beeing echo'ed later on in the code. There's no problem with the $result because I got around 10 other errors working the same in the code.

Comment: Why are you creating an iframe to do nothing except fire a JavaScript alert?

Comment: How does `$result` interact with the rest of your page? Is it output to an HTML document (and, if it is, does the source code of that HTML document look right to you? Can we see it? Remember you should aim for a **minimal** [mcve])? Is it output in response to an Ajax request? Something else?

Comment: @Quentin It's just to remove the "Message from **the url**" in iOS applications, there's no problem in the $result as I stated above. I got around 10 more errors working using the same code except the if(..)

Comment: What's exactly working here? Is the iframe showing up (*is it what you are trying to trigger*)? Is the statement `if(IsValidUser($reg_email) == 1)` running with the input you are expecting?

Comment: The problem is that the if(..) isn't triggering properly, here's how the $result works in all other if(..)'s, http://prntscr.com/cwowcl

Comment: The problem with the code I added is that the if(..) do not run at all, even if I'd use die(); it wouldn't do anything because the if(..) isn't running as it should.

Comment: @ChrisMeller Are you sure you are actually executing the if-statement in your code? If `IsValidUser($reg_email)` is `1` it will return `true` and run the code. Also do any error messages appear?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek This is how the whole page is; http://pastebin.com/26redL9b

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by placing the other if's under

```
else {
     if(..) {}
}
```